# Unlabeled instances in DOCCANO and SpaCY. Do they offer any value?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy, doccano

I am using doccano for sequence labelling and spacy for further modeling. Some of the sentences I label do not contain any of the labels I am interested in, so they remain "unlabeled" ie. no tags.

```
{"id": 79, "data": "This powerful charm would protect him until he became of age, or no longer called his aunt's house home.", "label": []}
{"id": 82, "data": "He began attending Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry in 1991.", "label": []}
{"id": 85, "data": "He later became the youngest Quidditch Seeker in over a century and eventually the captain of the Gryffindor House Quidditch Team in his sixth year, winning two Quidditch Cups.", "label": []}
```

I want to train SpaCy to recognise character names in all their variations.

Now the questions:

- is there any value in including unlabeled instances for the purpose of training SpaCy model?
- if there is then should I declare this data as "imbalanced dataset" and act accordingly? (boost? smote? over-sampling? etc.)
- what are the best practice in cases like this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: @Sergey Bushmanov Thank you for the edit. This was my fist ever question. Your edit was appreciated and it was very educational for a nubie like me. 
Спасибо, Сергей! Я благодарен Вам за правку.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to include some examples where nothing is labelled so the model can learn what *not* to label. For example, if in all your sample sentences all capitalized words are labelled, the model might learn to always label capitalized words.